# how to copy an entire row to sheet 2 if column H has a date in cell.?

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am trying to search (if column `H` in sheet `mechanical Equip.` has any date then copy entire row to sheet `off rent` next available row. It is coping the first row from `mechanical equip.` whether it has a date or not.

```
Sub CopyRowWithDates()
   Dim lrowcompleted As String
   Dim Rrange As Range

   Set Rrange = Sheets("MECHANICAL EQUIP.").Range("H2:H6000")

   On Error Resume Next
   Application.EnableEvents = False


        If Rrange = "mm/dd/yyy" Then

            lrowcompleted = Sheets("OFF RENT").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).ROW

            Range("A" & Rrange.ROW & ":N" & Rrange.ROW).Copy Sheets("OFF RENT").Range("A" & lrowcompleted + 1)
            Else
        End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

Comment: You have to create a loop and check each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i modified a different code i had and this one works the way i need it to. thanks for help.

```
   Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Dim id As String
Dim PO As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim lrowcompleted As String

id = TextBox19.Value
finalrow = Sheets("ALL P.O. INFO").Range("D6000").End(xlUp).row

For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Sheets("ALL P.O. INFO").Cells(i, 4) = id Then
        Sheets("ALL P.O. INFO").Cells(i, 8).Value = TextBox17.Value
    End If

    If Sheets("MECHANICAL EQUIP.").Cells(i, 4) = id Then
            Sheets("MECHANICAL EQUIP.").Cells(i, 8).Value = TextBox17.Value
            lrowcompleted = Sheets("OFF RENT").Range("A6000").End(xlUp).row
            Sheets("MECHANICAL EQUIP.").Range("A" & i & ":N" & i).Copy Sheets("OFF RENT").Range("A" & lrowcompleted + 1)


    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `For each myDate in range("H2:H6000")` instead of set range?

```
Sub CopyRowWithDates()
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Dim lrowcompleted As String
   Dim myDate as String

  For each myDate in range("H2:H6000")

   On Error Resume Next
   Application.EnableEvents = False

        If myDate = "mm/dd/yyy" Then

            lrowcompleted = Sheets("OFF RENT").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).ROW

            Range("A" & myDate.ROW & ":N" & myDate.ROW).Copy Sheets("OFF RENT").Range("A" & lrowcompleted + 1)
            Else
        End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Screenupdating = True
End Sub
```

I prefer to use `Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row`instead of `Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).ROW`

Comment: no that didn't help. not doing anything. i may have another option, just adding to a different code. i modified a different code i had and this one works.